# Autocomplete / suggest on each words

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make a suggest on each words by documents.

Example, I have tow sentences (tow documents) :

```
1) Hello world
2) Hello magic world
```

I know it's working for "Hello" but is it possible to suggest on "word" by typing "w" and "magic" to typing "t" too and return the complete sentence.

Comment: Maybe a term suggestion: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html